# Create postgresql function to be triggered before insert row

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, functions

I've created a function to be executed before inserting rows in a table, in order to avoid the error "malformed array literal". It still throws the error and I deduct that the process starts earlier than my trigger. Is there other trigger which I can use to intercept the event earlier?

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
permissions text[]
);

CREATE FUNCTION format_array() RETURNS trigger AS $func$
    BEGIN
        NEW.permissions := translate(NEW.permissions::text, '[]', '{}')::text[];
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER format_array BEFORE INSERT ON "user"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE format_array();

INSERT INTO "user" (permissions)
    VALUES ('["test", "test2"]');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ae1561db1f61f9458fabf02007f388ed

Comment: "*malformed array literal*" is a **syntax** error that is thrown before your statement even executes. There is no way to "fix" that in a trigger

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! Then, is there any way to intercept the SELECT  on "users", in order to return an altered "permissions" response to the webservice(from "{test, test2}" to '["test", "test2"]')?

Comment: You can create  view that returns a JSON value not a native array, e.g. using `to_jsonb()` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fc37a6778f9de651b9490c0c1a4c4b40

Comment: I hoped that I can intercept the selection on "permissions" automatically, like using a "trigger", but it looks that I don't have any other other choice than modifing the ORM framework, used in my backend web application.

Comment: Why not simply define the column as `jsonb` then you don't need to intercept anything.

Comment: Maybe you are right, at least I would adapt my own backend code to the new format not the ORM Framework. Thanks!